# SignatureDoesNotMatch.The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method

Tags: amazon-s3, electron, private, auto-update, electron-builder

I am trying to implement the auto-update functionality in an electron app using a private s3 bucket. but it giving me a signature mismatch error. Please can anyone help me with this?
I have used the following code structure,

```
let opts = {
service: 's3',
region: 'us-east-1',
host: 'bucket-name.s3.amazonaws.com',
path: '/latest.yml'
};
console.log(opts);

aws4.sign(opts, {
    accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
    secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
})
console.log(opts.headers);
autoUpdater.requestHeaders = opts.headers;


autoUpdater.checkForUpdates();
autoUpdater.on('checking-for-update', () => {

  })
```

Comment: Hey, I am facing the same issue. Any solution?

Comment: Hello, were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be the `/` before `latest.yml` in your opts. Removing it should work